# Why my logging aspect stops netty-websocket functions from being triggered?

Tags: java, websocket, aop, aspectj

My logging aspect stops the netty-websocket functions(OnOpen, OnMessage, etc.) from being triggered.

I have a netty-websocket based server, which executes some specified functions when connect to a new client or recieve messages. Those functions work properly.

Recently, I add a logging aspect to record detailed information of these functions. Unexpectedly, this stops these functions from being triggered (and the logging aspect itself does not work too).

The logging aspect works properly with other functions.

The logging aspect code:

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class ServiceLogAspect {

    @Around("execution(* com.test.server.WebSocketServer.onOpen(..))")
    public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
        Object result;
        System.out.println("around");
        try {
            result = jp.proceed();
            return result;
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

}
```

The websocket functions code:

```java
@ServerEndpoint(prefix = "netty-websocket")
@Component
public class WebSocketServer {
    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session, HttpHeaders headers, ParameterMap parameterMap) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("session:" + session + ", new connection"); // not executed
    }
```

I also tried @Before, which leads to the same failure.

```java
@Around("execution(* com.test.server.WebSocketServer.onOpen(..))")
public void beforeMethod(JoinPoint point) {
        System.out.println("before method");
    }
```

I consider this to be a conflict with annotations @onOpen. (@onMessage works fine).
How can I fix it and use logging aspect on such functions?

Comment: If you change your advice from `@Around` to `@Before` or `@After` and just print "logging", does it work? If so, then probably there is a problem in your around-advice which you don't show to us here because it is only pseudo code. Without an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) this is hard to tell with just fragments of your application class and an incomplete aspect.

Comment: @kriegaex Thx for apply, I tried `@Before`, which leads to the same failure. I have modify the code fragments in question, even the simplest around-advice doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I can see now that your aspect is annotated by `@Component`, so probably we are talking about Spring AOP here, not about AspectJ, correct? Nothing in your description or your tags suggested that. So we are dealing with an AOP approach which is based on dynamic JDK or CGLIB proxies, which might be part of the problem. But without a full MCVE I cannot tell. Can you please post one incl. Maven build on GitHub? I want to be able to compile and run your code in order to reproduce the problem. Your edit here definitely is not enough, sorry.